# Sample size estimation with power simulation in R: Same result for 2x2 and 2x3 ANOVAs?

Tags: r, statistics, simulation, anova

I am trying to estimate the necessary sample size for 2x2 and 2x3 within-subjects designs with power simulations in R:

1. simulating data in R with plausible main effects (30 milliseconds reaction time) and interaction effect that are minimally relevant to me (another overadditive 30 milliseconds reaction time),
2. calculating repeated-measures ANOVAs,
3. extracting the p-value for the interaction,
4. repeating the whole thing in a for loop to see how often the interactions are significant and get an estimate for the power

Strangely, I get the same sample size estimate for both design, although I think a larger sample should be necessary for the more complex 2x3 design than for the more simple 2x2 design. Is it because I set both main effects b2 and b3 to 30 and also both interaction effects ab22 and ab23 to 30 in the 2x3 design, so that it results in the same model as my 2x2 design?

Here is the code for the 2x2 design:

```
rep <- 200; n <- 350

# minimally relevant effect sizes
beta <- c(mu = 700, a2 = 30, b2 = 30, ab22 = 30) # a1, b1 := 0

dat <- expand.grid(A = factor(1:2), B = factor(1:2), subj = factor(1:n))
X <- model.matrix(~ A*B, dat)
Z <- model.matrix(~ 0 + subj + subj:A + subj:B, dat,
                  contrasts.arg = lapply(dat, contrasts, contrasts = FALSE))

pval <- NULL
# y = mu + a + b + ab + p + pa + pb + e
for (i in 1:rep){
  y <- X %*% beta + # mu, a, b, ab (fixed factor effects)
    Z %*% c(p = rnorm(n, sd = 100), pa = rnorm(2*n, sd = 100),
            pb = rnorm(2*n, sd = 100)) + # p, pa, pb (random participants effects)
    rnorm(4*n, sd = 100) # e (error term for residuals)
  m <- aov(y ~ A*B + Error(subj + subj:A + subj:B), dat)
  pval <- c(pval, summary(m)$"Error: Within"[[1]]$"Pr(>F)"[1])
}
mean(pval < 0.05)
```

Here is the code for the 2x3 design:

```
rep <- 200; n <- 350

# minimally relevant effect sizes
beta <- c(mu = 700, a2 = 30, b2 = 30, b3 = 30, ab22 = 30, ab23 = 30) # a1, b1 := 0

dat <- expand.grid(A = factor(1:2), B = factor(1:3), subj = factor(1:n))
X <- model.matrix(~ A*B, dat)
Z <- model.matrix(~ 0 + subj + subj:A + subj:B, dat,
                  contrasts.arg = lapply(dat, contrasts, contrasts = FALSE))

pval <- NULL
for (i in 1:rep){
  y <- X %*% beta + # mu, a, b, ab (fixed factor effects)
    Z %*% c(p = rnorm(n, sd = 100), pa = rnorm(2*n, sd = 100),
            pb = rnorm(3*n, sd = 100)) +  # p, pa, pb (random participants effects)
    rnorm(6*n, sd = 100) # is e (error term for residuals)
  m <- aov(y ~ A*B + Error(subj + subj:A + subj:B), dat)
  pval <- c(pval, summary(m)$"Error: Within"[[1]]$"Pr(>F)"[1])
}
mean(pval < 0.05)
```